# Specify a configuration when WebTestCase is used for functional testing a bundle?

Tags: testing, symfony, bundle, functional-testing

What I'm trying to do is to functional test my bundle (a reusable one). More in deep:

- Create a request to a given url `/my/url`
- Check that `MyParamConverter` is invoked and converts the request into an instance of `MyObject`
- Check that the controller throws `my.event`

As per documentation I should extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` and create a new client:

```php
    $client  = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/my/url');
```

Doing it this way, which bundles are loaded? How can I specify a configuration file to use in the environment (assuming it's default to `test`)?

**EDIT**: Ok, time to explain better my question. I'm wring a reusable bundle, say AcmeMessagingBundle. Now I want to functional test it. Scenario is a call to `/my/url`:

```php
public function testReceiveApiRoute()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();

    /** @var $route \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route */
    $route  = $client->getContainer()->get('router')
        ->getRouteCollection()->get('acme_messaging_receive');

    $this->assertNotNull($route);
    $this->assertEquals('POST', $route->getRequirement('_method'));
    $this->assertEquals('acme_messaging.controller.api:receive',
        $route->getDefault('_controller'));
}

/**
 * @depends testReceiveApiRoute
 */
public funcion testReceiveApiWorkflow()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();

    // Make a POST request
    $request = Request::create('/my/route', 'POST', array(
        'a' => 'value'
    ));

    // Request is convered in MyObject instance and that my.event is fired
}
```

With this test, `app/config_test.yml` is loaded (say "main config file"). Question is:

Shouldn't test be "isolated", meaning not using the main config file? What if my bundle is tested by another person with an empty `app/config_test.yml`? Test would fail...

The test will fail also with a prefixed route. If `routing.xml` from AcmeMessagingBundle is imported with a prefix, `testReceiveApiWorkflow` is going to fail!

Comment: I can't understand your question. What do you mean by "loaded bundles"? Did you mean how to specify custom web test client? Or maybe you are not sure which config files are loaded? Please, give me some clarification

Comment: @Cyprian I don't know which config file is going to be loaded. I would assume the "main" `config_test.yml` (in app/config) which in turn loads `config_dev.yml`. What I'd like to know is: is this a good practice? How can i use a config file from `/Tests/Fixture/config_test.yml` instead of `app/config/config_test.yml`?

Comment: I think for your goals will be sufficient if you just add service named "test.client" in your Bundle\Resources\config\services.yml (or xml). This file is loaded by DI\Extension file and framework will deal with "test.client" name in that way it will be using your service instead default WebTestClient. However, to load additional config file this article might be useful for you: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html . Greetings!

Comment: @Cyprian I've tried to explain better my question. Look at my edits, hope what you can understand what I'm meaning. Unfortunately my bad english combined with my poor Symfony 2 internals understanding make this harder :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `WebTestCase` will use your own `AppKernel` with the test environment.

You can either add a new env to your app, and use it in the `WebTestCase` like this:

```
$client = static::createClient(array('environment' => 'new_env'));
```

A safer practice would be to create an app sanboxed in your bundle's tests.
You can use [JMSCommandBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSCommandBundle%20) to generate it for you.
You could also create the sanboxed application looking at bundles using this trick: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/tree/master/Tests/Functional

Comment: I've updated my question. The last solution seems what I'm meaning, but I should investigate further...